# Intermittent failure of keyboard notofications

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I have a view (a couple of them actually) with a standard search bar at the bottom.  When the user touches the search bar, I need to move the search bar up so it's not hidden by the keyboard, then down again when the keyboard is dismissed.

I do this the same way as everybody else, by observing `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`.  From these notifications, I get the height of the keyboard, and that tells me where to put the bottom edge of the search bar.  It works perfectly, except for rare cases when the search bar doesn't animate, or doesn't animate far enough, and vanishes behind the keyboard.  I have seen this a handful of times out of hundreds of tries with myself and my QA people testing on iPhones and iPods.  Just once, I saw the search bar fly off the top of the screen as the keyboard came up. We've never seen any of this on the simulator, and we see it more often on the iPod than the iPhone.  We are running iOS 4.x, mostly 4.3.3.

So I can think of two possibilities.  One is that very occasionally `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is not sent and the other is that the data in the notification is wrong.  The second one would explain the one case where the search bar flew off the top of the screen.

And then of course it is possible that my code is wrong in some very devious way; but the scenario is so simple -- enter the view and tap the search bar -- that I can't see how a bug in my code could cause these rare and intermittent failures.

If anyone can offer insight, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered the answer to my question, and it's interesting.  To cut to the chase, my search bar is animating into the wrong position; in some cases it's still behind the keyboard, and in others it's off the top of the screen.  This is not caused by wrong data in the notification, but by a bug in accessing the height member of a CGSize or the y member of a CGPoint.

Specifically: in certain scenarios, when you write mySize.height, the generated code accesses mySize.width.  If you are reading, you get the value of mySize.width; if you are writing, you clobber mySize.width.  Similarly, myPoint.y actually accesses myPoint.x.

You may never see this problem.  I only saw it on older iPod touch devices running iOS 4.2.1, and only in Release builds, and only when compiling with Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0, and then maybe only sometimes.  But I reported it to Apple and they say it's a duplicate of a known bug (#10043857) that they are addressing.  Connecting a few dots, I am guessing that it's somewhere in the compiler chain in Xcode 4.2.

The workaround is to take the address of the CGSize or CGPoint struct, then use pointer arithmetic to access the desired member.  I wrote a set of little helper functions to do this, and I call them all over my app's code.

Comment: I've found that rect handed to you by the keyboard notifications doesn't adapt width and height to the orientation of the device. Are you sure that you're properly converting the coordinates to the view's coordinate system that contains the search bar?

Comment: I do account for device orientation when doing the keyboard animation, and it works reliably as long as I don't run a Release build on an older iPod running 4.2.1.